# How can I assign the value to textEdit limitedly via pushButton in python?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm going to design an alarm clock in python and pyqt4.

There are some problems that confused me, firstly, I want to know how to give the fixed length for each textEdit to set time (or use another method to set). 
And secondly, because of my code I wrote, when I clicked the button, the textEdit would only showed "ONE" value ; that is, if you click button "one", textEdit show "1"; however, if you click button "two", textEdit will show "2" not "12". I don't know why.......

Here is my code.  I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
try:
  _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
def _fromUtf8(s):
    return s
try:
_encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
def _translate(context, text, disambig):
    return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
def _translate(context, text, disambig):
    return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class setalarmclock(QtGui.QWidget):
def __init__(self, parent = None):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
def setupUi(self, Form):
    Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
    Form.resize(495, 397)
    sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(Form.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    Form.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    Form.setAutoFillBackground(True)
    self.widget = QtGui.QWidget(Form)
    self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 481, 371))
    self.widget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("widget"))
    self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.widget)
    self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 10, 471, 341))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Arial"))
    font.setPointSize(16)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.tabWidget.setFont(font)
    self.tabWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tabWidget"))
    self.tab = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.tab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab"))
    self.gridLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self.tab)
    self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 90, 391, 208))
    self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayoutWidget"))
    self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
    self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Arial"))
    font.setPointSize(22)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton_5 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Arial"))
    font.setPointSize(22)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_5"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_5, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton_4 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Arial"))
    font.setPointSize(22)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_4"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 1, 0, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton_8 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Arial"))
    font.setPointSize(22)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.pushButton_8.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton_8.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_8"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_8, 2, 1, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton_6 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Arial"))
    font.setPointSize(22)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.pushButton_6.setFont(font)self.pushButton_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_6"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_6, 1, 2, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
    self.pushButton.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
    self.pushButton.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Arial"))
    font.setPointSize(22)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.pushButton.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton.setAutoFillBackground(False)
    self.pushButton.setCheckable(False)
    self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton_7 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Arial"))
    font.setPointSize(22)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.pushButton_7.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton_7.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_7"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_7, 2, 0, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton_9 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Arial"))
    font.setPointSize(22)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.pushButton_9.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton_9.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_9"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_9, 2, 2, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Arial"))
    font.setPointSize(22)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_3"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 0, 2, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton_10 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Arial"))
    font.setPointSize(22)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.pushButton_10.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton_10.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_10"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_10, 3, 1, 1, 1)
    self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.tab)
    self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 30, 101, 51))
    self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))
    self.textEdit_2 = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.tab)
    self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 30, 104, 51))
    self.textEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit_2"))
    self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.tab)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 30, 111, 51))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Arial"))
    font.setPointSize(20)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.label.setFont(font)
    self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
    self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.tab)
    self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 30, 31, 51))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Arial"))
    font.setPointSize(20)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.label_2.setFont(font)
    self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
    self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, _fromUtf8(""))
    self.tab_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.tab_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab_2"))
    self.gridLayoutWidget_2 = QtGui.QWidget(self.tab_2)
    self.gridLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 180, 441, 111))
    self.gridLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayoutWidget_2"))
    self.gridLayout_2 = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
    self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout_2"))
    self.pushButton_11 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(22)
    self.pushButton_11.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton_11.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_11"))
    self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_11, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton_14 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(22)
    self.pushButton_14.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton_14.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_14"))
    self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_14, 0, 3, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton_13 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(22)
    self.pushButton_13.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton_13.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_13"))
    self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_13, 0, 2, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton_12 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(22)
    self.pushButton_12.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton_12.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_12"))
    self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_12, 0, 1, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton_15 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(22)
    self.pushButton_15.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton_15.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_15"))
    self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_15, 1, 0, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton_16 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(22)
    self.pushButton_16.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton_16.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_16"))
    self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_16, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton_17 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(22)
    self.pushButton_17.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton_17.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_17"))
    self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_17, 1, 2, 1, 1)
    self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(self.tab_2)
    self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 51, 51))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(20)
    self.label_3.setFont(font)
    self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
    self.textEdit_3 = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.tab_2)
    self.textEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 60, 361, 51))
    self.textEdit_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit_3"))
    self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, _fromUtf8(""))
    self.tab_3 = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.tab_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab_3"))
    self.radioButton = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.tab_3)
    self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 25, 83, 41))
    self.radioButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("radioButton"))
    self.radioButton_2 = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.tab_3)
    self.radioButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 83, 41))
    self.radioButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("radioButton_2"))
    self.radioButton_3 = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.tab_3)
    self.radioButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 140, 83, 41))
    self.radioButton_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("radioButton_3"))
    self.textEdit_4 = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.tab_3)
    self.textEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 140, 321, 41))
    self.textEdit_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit_4"))
    self.pushButton_18 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
    self.pushButton_18.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 250, 105, 45))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(22)
    self.pushButton_18.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton_18.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_18"))
    self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, _fromUtf8(""))

    self.retranslateUi(Form)
    self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

def retranslateUi(self, Form):
    Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Alarm Clock", None))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "1", None))
    self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "2", None))
    self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "3", None))
    self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Form", "4", None))
    self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("Form", "5", None))
    self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("Form", "6", None))
    self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("Form", "7", None))
    self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("Form", "8", None))        
    self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("Form", "9", None))        
    self.pushButton_10.setText(_translate("Form", "0", None))
    self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "TIME SET", None))
    self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "：", None))
    self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("Form", "TIME", None))
    self.pushButton_11.setText(_translate("Form", "MON.", None))
    self.pushButton_12.setText(_translate("Form", "TUE.", None))
    self.pushButton_13.setText(_translate("Form", "WED.", None))  
    self.pushButton_14.setText(_translate("Form", "THU.", None))
    self.pushButton_15.setText(_translate("Form", "FRI.", None))
    self.pushButton_16.setText(_translate("Form", "SAT.", None))
    self.pushButton_17.setText(_translate("Form", "SUN.", None))
    self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "週期", None))
    self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("Form", "PERIOD", None))
    self.radioButton.setText(_translate("Form", "1", None))
    self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "2", None))
    self.radioButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "3", None))
    self.pushButton_18.setText(_translate("Form", "FINISH", None))
    self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("Form", "RINGSTONE", None))

    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.set1)
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.set2)
    self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.set3)
    self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.set4)
    self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.set5)
    self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.set6)
    self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.set7)
    self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.set8)
    self.pushButton_9.clicked.connect(self.set9)
    self.pushButton_10.clicked.connect(self.set0)
    self.radioButton_3.clicked.connect(self.filebroswer)

def set1(self,Form):
    print 
def set2(self,Form):
    self.textEdit.setText("2")
def set3(self,Form):
    self.textEdit.setText("3")
def set4(self,Form):
    self.textEdit.setText("4")
def set5(self,Form):
    self.textEdit.setText("5")
def set6(self,Form):
    self.textEdit.setText("6")
def set7(self,Form):
    self.textEdit.setText("7")
def set8(self,Form):
    self.textEdit.setText("8")
def set9(self,Form):
    self.textEdit.setText("9")
def set0(self,Form):
    self.textEdit.setText("0")

def filebroswer(self,Form):
    filter = "mp3(*.mp3)"
    filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNameAndFilter(self,"Open file", "C:\\Users\\MIS\\Desktop", filter)
    self.textEdit_4.setText(filename[0])
if __name__ == 'main':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = setalarmclock()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Andy, I put my code. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setText` function of `QTextEdit` does it's job correctly: it's set the text.
 If you call `textEdit.setText("2")`, the text of the textEdit becomes "2" and the previous text is erased.

What you want is `QTextEdit.append()`. It writes by default on a new line, but there are [some workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559990/qt-append-text-to-qplaintextedit-without-adding-newline-and-keep-scroll-at-the). If you don't need multiple line, you could use a `QLineEdit`.

Answer (score 0):

`self.textEdit.setText()` should clear text before setting new one. But if it won't work, try to add `self.textEdit.clear()` before it.

If you want to append text, use `self.textEdit.append()`

If you want a fixed size for the text edit, add `self.textEdit.setFixedSize()` with the size that you prefer.