# Get output of cmd command in real time in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

Im using this code in Qt to get output of a cmd commend

```cpp
     QProcess c_output;
     c_output.start("some-exe", QStringList() << "param1" << "param2" << "param3...");
     if (!c_output.waitForStarted())
         std::cout << false;

     c_output.write("...");
     c_output.closeWriteChannel();

     if (!c_output.waitForFinished())
         std::cout << false;
```

its work just good.
with this code i can access output with `c_output.readAll()`, but problem is this code wait until cmd finish exec ... and then give all output in `c_output.readAll()`, i want to get output in realtime and show them in gui of my program
my mean is my commend print multiply lines after exec, i want to show all of them one by one in my program and not wait for it to finish.

Comment: like in another thread?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ you talk about what thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `waitForReadyRead` instead of the `waitForFinished` , see at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#waitForReadyRead

Here is a simple example with the usage:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    QProcess c_output;
    c_output.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
     c_output.start("dmesg", QStringList() << "-w");
     if (!c_output.waitForStarted()){
         qDebug() << "Failed to start";
        return -1;
     }

     c_output.write("...");
     c_output.closeWriteChannel();

     while (c_output.state() != QProcess::NotRunning)
     {
        qDebug() << ".";
        if (c_output.waitForReadyRead())
         qDebug() << "c_output" << c_output.readAllStandardOutput();
     }


    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: after that how can i use c_output.readAll() to read the output?

Comment: thanks for good example, can you please show example for showing in gui? i mean append output in exiting text

Comment: I think this is out of scope for this question. See for example this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559990/how-to-append-text-to-qplaintextedit-without-adding-newline-and-keep-scroll-at 
or state a separated question with your exact issue.

Comment: a problem i found in your code is it show \r\n and its also some time merge line

Comment: i think its because im in the window and i think its use \r\n for going to next line

Comment: This also depends on the format of the output of the executable, so i can't guide you with a specific example, but you can try to use the combination  of `canReadLine() ` and `readLine()` methods as well to get separated lines.